# libc dependency while uplifting redis library from 6.2.12 to 6.2.13

Tags: redis, glibc, libc

I am using Oracle Linux 7, which is similar to redhat 7. In this, the default supported libc version is libc-2.17.so.
With the above setup, when we install Redis 6.2.12 version, everything seems to be working properly. Recently, I have uplifted to Redis 6.2.13 and there is a direct dependency on libc library.
It specifically requires libc-2.28.so instead of libc-2.17.so. However, in the previous version of Redis i.e 6.2.12, the libc used was libc-2.17.so.

NOTE : From what I understand, libc-2.28.so is generally available from linux 8 onwards.
So, can someone please let me know if the dependency on libc-2.28.so is added intentionally for Redis 6.2.12? If not, how this dependency can be resolved ?